# Can you use Python v. 2.7 with Django?

Tags: python, django, compatibility

The Django book says: "The core Django framework works with any Python version from 2.3 to 2.6, inclusive. Django’s optional GIS (Geographic Information Systems) support requires Python 2.4 to 2.6."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Django's FAQ](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/faq/install/):

> Currently, Django itself officially supports any version of Python from 2.4 through 2.7, inclusive.

The Django Book (2nd edition) is written for Django version 1.0, while the latest release of Django is version 1.2.1, hence the difference.

Comment: Well actually, the reason is that the Django Book was written before the release of Python 2.7. The only reason for the upper limit was to emphasise that Django is *not* compatible with Python 3+, which has some backwards incompatibilities.

Comment: For anyone's reference, more details here re Django and Python versions: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/